# Clases y Constructor en Php con parametros

Tags: php

Hola buenos dias comunidad, Estoy aprendiendo el uso de poo en PHP tengo el siguiente codigo, deseo sumar 2 numeros, tengo una clase y un constructor, al cual le paso 3 parametros en json, 2 numeros y una opcion, me muestra varios mensajes de error entre ellos "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function operaciones::sumar()".

Este es el codigo:

//php 7.2.24

```
class operaciones
{

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->Main($data);
    }
    public function Main($data)
    {
        switch ($data->option) {
            case "suma":
                $this->sumar($data);
            break; 
        }
    }
     public function sumar($data)
     {
         $numero1=$data->num1;
         $numero2=$data->num2;
         return $thhis->$numero1+$numero2;
     }
}

$data = json_decode('{"option":"suma","num1":1,"num2":5}');
$op = new operaciones($data);
echo $op->sumar();
```

Comment: probablemente el error sea en la linea "echo $op->sumar()", puesto que no le pasas argumentos al metodo "sumar" del objeto Operaciones que has definido. Fijate que tu clase, cuando se llama al constructor, este llama a la funcion main, y esta a su vez llama a la funcion sumar (con los datos del constructor). No seria necesaria esa linea, puesto que ya se resuelve el problema al iniciar la clase operaciones.

Comment: aparte, tienes varios errores: en la funcion suma, tienes un `$thhis` que sobra, puesto que ya has guardado los numeros en sus variables (que no hacia falta). El modelado de la clase tiene sus problemas, porque tienes todas las funciones como public, lo que hace que no quede claro si es Main el punto de entrada, o es sumar, o ambas... Tu programa puede funcionar si en el `echo $op->sumar();` añades el $data como parametro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola hice los siguientes ajustes con el aporte de @Jakala, si me funciona me da la siguiente salida, pero da una Warning..

{"status":"true","message":"La Multiplicacion de:2 * 6 = 12"}

PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in 1126113075/source.php on line 26

```
<?php //php 7.2.24
class operaciones
{   
    public function __constructor($data)
    {
        $this->Main($data);
    }
    function Main($data)
    {
        switch ($data->option) {
            case "suma":
            $this->sumar($data);
            break;
            case "multiplicacion":
            $this->multiplicar($data);
            break;
        }

    }
    function sumar($data){
        $response->status="true";
        $response->message="La Suma de:".$data->num1." + ".$data->num2." = ".($data->num1+$data->num2)."";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    function multiplicar($data){
        $response->status="true";
        $response->message="La Multiplicacion de:".$data->num1." * ".$data->num2." = ".($data->num1*$data->num2)."";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
$data = json_decode('{"num1":2,"num2":6, "option":"multiplicacion"}');
$op = new operaciones;
$op->Main($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes un método `Main()` que "lee" la operación incluida en el JSON (suma, resta,...) y llama a la función respectiva. Pero en otro lado también veo que llamas directamente al método de `sumar()`.

Para hacer que funcionen ambos casos, le cambiaré el nombre al método `Main` por `auto_operacion()` (para ser más descriptivos), donde se va a leer la instrucción del JSON y llamará a al método adecuado para resolver la operación.

A su vez, también se podrán llamar a los métodos que hacen las operaciones por separado:

```php
<?php

class operaciones {
    
    private $data;
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    
    public function auto_operacion() {
        switch($this->data->option) {
            case 'suma':
                $res = 'La suma es: '. $this->sumar();
            break;
            case 'resta':
                $res = 'La resta es: '. $this->restar();
            break;
            case 'multiplicacion':
                $res = 'La multiplicacion es: '. $this->multiplicar();
            break;
            case 'division':
                $res = 'La division es: '. $this->dividir();
            break;
            default:
                $res = "Error, no existe esa operacion";
        }
        return $res;
    }
    
    public function sumar() {
        return $this->data->num1 + $this->data->num2;
    }
    
    public function restar() {
        return $this->data->num1 - $this->data->num2;
    }
    
    public function multiplicar() {
        return $this->data->num1 * $this->data->num2;
    }
    
    public function dividir() {
        if ($this->data->num2 != 0) {
            return $this->data->num1 / $this->data->num2;
        }
        return 'Error, division por cero';
    }
}
```

Uso:

```php
$data = json_decode('{"option":"suma", "num1":2, "num2":6}');
$op = new operaciones($data);
echo $op->auto_operacion(); // La suma es: 8
echo $op->sumar(); // 8
echo $op->multiplicar(); // 12
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, asi como lo planteas se entiende mejor el codigo... saludos!!